# How to change variable in NASM (x86, Microsoft Windows 10)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I want to change the value of a variable in NASM.

I searched the internet for a long time and I tried a lot of things.

I've tried this:

```
global  _main
extern  _printf

section .data
original: db "Hello, world", 10, 0
new: db "Hello", 10, 0

section .text
_main:
    mov [original], new

    push original
    call _printf
    add esp, 4

    ret
```

This does not works, so I've tried this.

```
global  _main
extern  _printf

section .data
original: db "Hello, world", 10, 0
new: db "Hello", 10, 0

section .text
_main:
    mov eax, new
    mov [original], eax

    push original
    call _printf
    add esp, 4

    ret
```

Well, it works without errors, but it keeps printing weird things.

```
@@
```

(Actually, there were arrow-shaped characters pointing up and down at the beginning of the string above, but I omitted it because it did not seem to be recognized)

I've tried and searched a lot of things. But I couldn't find a solution.
So how can I change the value of a variable in NASM? (I'm using x86 assembly in Windows)

Thanks.

Comment: Is this 32 or 64 bit code?  How do you assemble and link this code?

Comment: @fuz It is how I compiled
```nasm -f win32 print.asm```
```gcc print.obj -o print.exe```

Comment: You're printing the pointer value as ASCII bytes, not the pointed-to memory.  Just pass a pointer to `new`, or modify a `ptr: dd original` and then reload it.

Comment: are you trying to change the string (copy it over top) or are you trying to point at the new string (push new instead of push original)?

Comment: @old_timer I'm going to change value of original to value of new and push original. So what I want is to be printed "Hello."

Comment: the string is a string, an array of bytes, i tis not a value.  the address to it is a value.  but you are referencing a label, so your choices are to push new instead of push original, from your code that is how you change the "value"  otherwise you need to create a pointer, which you are free to default to point at original then you can change that pointer to point at new instead.

Comment: *There are no variables in assembly*

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overwrite a string using a single instruction. You need to use a loop to copy the bytes of the string, while checking for the null byte that marks the end of the string. For example:

```
        mov edi, original
        mov esi, new
.loop:
        mov al, [esi]
        mov [edi], al
        add esi, 1
        add edi, 1
        test al, al
        jnz .loop
```

Comment: This code is for a general string copy. In your example, since you know the the length of the old and new strings, you can do it in a few instructions: `mov eax, [new] / mov [original], eax / mov eax, [new+4] / mov [original+4], eax`. This copies one byte more than the actual string length, which is *usually* safe, but should only be done if you *know* it is safe.

Comment: The registers edi and esi must be preserved by your function, so you should push them at the beginning of the function and pop them at the end before the return. Alternatively, use `ecx` and `edx` as the pointers, which don’t need to be preserved.

Comment: To do a 7-byte copy, you could use glibc memcpy's / memmove's strategy of two *overlapping* 4-byte loads, and two stores.  It doesn't matter than the middle byte gets written twice.